# Application object is being shut down exception

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I'm developing an Excel add-in using multiple windows forms and multiple Element host objects to contain WPF controls. I also have a form which calls to a web service. And displays the results back to Excel.

The problem I'm currently facing is the current : After some interaction with the addin ( no specific order has been found ) my addin stops behaving correctly, throwing an invalid operation exception somewhere inside the PresentationFramework.dll . I can't inspect the code that's running in there because it's hidden.

The Exception says the following : "Application object is being shut down".

What could be causing this?

It is thrown at initialization of a control that is used for some custom drawings

```
        InitializeComponent();
```

The stack trace looks like this :

> at System.Windows.Application.GetResourcePackage(Uri packageUri)\r\n   at System.Windows.Application.GetResourceOrContentPart(Uri uri)\r\n   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)\r\n   at Drawing.MoleculeView.InitializeComponent() in d:\Projects\Common\Depict\Drawing\MoleculeView.xaml:line 1\r\n   at Drawing.MoleculeView..ctor() in d:\Projects\Common\Depict\Drawing\MoleculeView.xaml.cs:line 192\r\n   at DrawingControlWrapper.MultipleDrawingControl.LoadMolecule(Molecule molecules, Point[] bounds) in c:\Users\Nikolay\Desktop\Addin\DrawingControlWrapper\MultipleDrawingControl.xaml.cs:line 32\r\n   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , MultipleDrawingControl , Object , Point[] )\r\n   at LMCExcelFunctions.ThisAddIn.QueueMolecule(Object mol) in c:\Users\Nikolay\Desktop\Addin\LMCExcelFunctions\ThisAddIn.cs:line 182\r\n   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )\r\n   at LMCExcelFunctions.ThisAddIn.addin_SheetSelectionChange(Object sh, Range target) in c:\Users\Nikolay\Desktop\Addin\LMCExcelFunctions\ThisAddIn.cs:line 93

XAML looks like this :

```
<UserControl x:Class="Drawing.MoleculeView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <DockPanel x:Name="layout"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Just a tip: add original exception + stacktrace + the code snippet where it is thrown. it helps to identify the problem and you might get an answer way faster

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that's what I managed to dig out.

Comment: I have it,altho I'm certain that the XAML is clean of problems, I will post it too.

Comment: It's kinda like to ask a pilot to land a plane with a blindfold you know...

Comment: That looks ok ... you probably add some controls to the layout... do you have that code?

Comment: If there's an exception coming from the InitializeComponent(); shouldn't it be localized for the initialization of that control since it is called first thus no controls are added? I do add controls afterwards but that's after the initialization.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71692/discussion-between-florian-schmidinger-and-chris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by using an inner Element Host : it appears that any control that is being created by a control which is hosted inside an element host must also have its own element host.

Comment: It would be immensely helpful if you could post the changes in xaml or code you made to solve this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou you can check out the ElementHost object, I was working for a corporate company at the time, so I don't have access to that code anymore,sorry :(

Answer (score 33):

If you set Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown you problem should go away.

Comment: This was usefull to me when I wanted to display a WPF window (possibly multiple times) in a WinForm application.

Comment: Same as @Huhra, this solved the same problem for me when using many WPF objects in  ElementHosts in a WinForm app - our app has to close and reopen the main form on user request, which was resulting in the OP's error.

Answer (score 3):

Wpf controls need an instance of application but but winForm doesn't instantiate the  wpf application.
you can resolve it by the following code at application startup:

```
        System.Windows.Application app = new System.Windows.Application()
    {
        ShutdownMode = Windows.ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown
    };
    Closed += () =>
    {
        app.Shutdown();
    };
```

or in Vb.net:

```
Dim app As System.Windows.Application = New System.Windows.Application With {
.ShutdownMode = Windows.ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown
AddHandler Closed, Sub()
                               app.Shutdown()
                           End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In got this exception when running an automated test checking that the service initialization code running just before showing the main window of a WPF app succeeds:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    // Code to init some services...

    if (isTestRun)
    {
        // Service init code succeeds, quit the app without showing the main window.
        Shutdown(exitCode: 0); // -> This line throws the exception.
    }
    else
    {
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

Replacing the offending line with

```
Current.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
```

resolved the issue.

Please note that:

1. The code above belongs a class deriving from `System.Windows.Application`.
2. The *exact problem* was that the offending line caused the automated tests running with STA attribute to fail.